# Ubuntu 20.04.2 Temporary Failure in name resolution

Tags: networking, internet, dns, kvm-virtualization, connection

About 2 weeks ago my VM became unreachable from the Internet - I can't access it via ssh, I can't access the files stored on it but I *can* ping it. I have KVM VNC Setup for it so I logged on and I tried to ping google.com but it resulted in the Temporary failure in name resolution error. However, it is successfully able to ping IPs directly such as the 1.1.1.1 DNS Server and any public IP.

I've been trying to debug this issue for the past 2 weeks now but it has ultimately lead me here as I feel that I've tried everything publicly available regarding this issue. I'd greatly appreciate if anyone can help me resolve this!

**I ran these commands on the vm via KVM VNC:**

**ping google.com**

```
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

**ping -c 1 1.1.1.1**

```
PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=8.38 ms
```

1 packet transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss

**sudo ufw status**

```
Status: Inactive
```

**nmap localhost**

- *says host is up*
- *"Not shown: 999 closed ports"*
- *Port 22/tcp is in open state (ssh)*

**ip addr**

- [ip addr command output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iC6A.jpg)

**cat /etc/resolv.conf**

- [contents of resolve file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfBae.jpg)
- it is symlinked to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

Comment: Can you post the contents of /etc/resolv.conf

Comment: Yeah it didn't let me edit my existing post with another image so here's a link to it anyway -> https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kf4I.jpg also it's symlinked to /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf

Comment: Wait, I was able to add the image to orignal post now